# hide page url asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I want to hide page name in browser.

For example;

```
www.mysite.com/page1.aspx
www.mysite.com/page2.aspx
www.mysite.com/page3.aspx
```

I want to appear all sites like this: www.mysite.com

How can I do this in asp.net 3.5 with IIS 6.0.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this? I would recommend against it as whatever result you are trying to achieve can probably be achieved in a better way

Comment: 'www.mysite.com/' is not a valid virtual path. error ??

Answer (score 3):

See ScottGu's explanation about this issue here : [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But I m looking for a simple solution than this. I have just these 3 pages.

Comment: Possible I misunderstand what you want. But is it really difficult to write one function for this issue following the first approach mentioned in this article, for example?

Answer (score 2):

use ajax to load your content or use one big `<frameset>`.

But, **don't do it**. It will break the possibility for users to make bookmarks, make it harder / impossible for Google to crawl your website.

Comment: Agreed.  Avoid the <frameset> at all costs.  It also does not play nicely on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscating the actual URL is [**very bad practice**](http://universalusability.com/access_by_design/frames/avoid.html) both in usability and debugging.

If you really, really need to do it you can use HTML frames by having a parent frameset page at your desired url and your actual pages in a full-width full-height frame inside the frameset.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx).  Create a new `Uri` object and then use the `Host` method.

Answer (score 0):

how do you identify what page you should use?

Your could use url rewriting module(iis) for friendly urls like these:

www.mysite.com/page/1

www.mysite.com/page/2

www.mysite.com/page/3

Comment: Thanks. But I m looking for a simple solution than this. I have just these 3 pages. I dont want to display page name in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate and having trouble with other options you could do the follow.  I definitely wouldn't recommend this approach because it's ugly but it would probably get the job done:

1. On www.mysite.com/page[1|2|3].aspx Page_Load method, issue a Response.Redirect("www.mysite.com/") if and only if Request.UrlReferrer is not www.mysite.com/page[1|2|3].aspx
2. On www.mysite.com/[default.aspx], issue a Server.Transfer("page[1|2|3].aspx") if the Request.UrlReferrer is www.mysite.com/page[1|2|3].aspx.  Server.Transfer will pull the page on the server side and respond with the result, rather than issuing a 301 redirect so the user will still see www.mysite.com/ on their browser.